# parse module version number to see if it's greater than the required number in Python

Tags: parsing, version

I know for Python version, you can

```
if sys.version_info < (2,8):
    print 'there will be no Python 2.8!'
```

But, is there a similar way to do this for a module?

Right now I am doing something like:

```
# in case like '1.8.1rc', need to filter for numbers
ver = [int(filter(lambda x : x.isdigit(), n)) for n in np.__version__.split('.')]
ver.reverse()
if sum([v * 10 ** n for n,v in enumerate(ver)]) < 181:
    print "np.unique before gh-2799: allow using unique with lists of complex"
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. I could not believe Python does not have a solution for this. So, I did search but somehow could not find this. Thanks!

Comment: No one can ever seem to agree on what a 'version' should be, so that's why there is no language support for it, only conventions used by various tools like `distutils`.